# Upgrade from Magento 2.3.3 to Magento 2.4.2 gives error on qbo/module-paypalplusmx

Tags: magento, migration, magento2, magento-2.3

I am getting an error while upgrading from Magento 2.3.3 to 2.4.2.
While running composer update I am getting one issue i.e.

```
qbo/module-paypalplusmx 2.3.3-RC requires magento/framework 100.0.*|100.1.*|101.0.*|102.0.* -> satisfiable by magento/framework[102.0.3, 102.0.6-p1, 102.0.6, 102.0.5-p2, 102.0.4-p2, 102.0.5, 102.0.3-p1, 102.0.4, 101.0.11, 102.0.2-p2, 101.0.10, 101.0.9, 100.1.18, 102.0.2, 101.0.8, 102.0.1, 100.1.17, 102.0.0, 101.0.7, 100.1.16, 101.0.6, 100.1.15, 100.1.14, 101.0.5, 101.0.4, 100.1.13, 101.0.3, 100.1.12, 100.0.20, 101.0.2, 100.1.11, 100.1.10, 101.0.1, 100.0.19, 101.0.0, 100.0.18, 100.1.9, 101.0.0-rc30, 101.0.0-rc23, 101.0.0-rc22, 101.0.0-rc21, 100.1.8, 100.0.17, 100.0.16, 100.1.7, 100.1.6, 100.0.15, 100.1.5, 100.0.14, 100.1.4, 100.0.13, 100.1.3, 100.1.2, 100.0.12, 100.1.1, 100.0.11, 100.0.10, 100.1.0, 100.1.0-rc3, 100.1.0-rc2, 100.1.0-rc1, 100.0.9, 100.0.8, 100.0.7, 100.0.6, 100.0.5, 100.0.4, 100.0.3, 100.0.2].
    - Installation request for qbo/module-paypalplusmx ^2.3.3-RC -> satisfiable by qbo/module-paypalplusmx[2.3.3-RC]
```

I am using Xampp 7.4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution by overriding the module in app/code.
After that I defined the version dependency in composer.json file & it worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

It was caused by the paypalplusmx (qbo/module-paypalplusmx) extension, which is incompatible with 2.4.